# Decoding timestamp for evtest in linux terminal

Tags: linux, unix, input, terminal, timestamp

I am using evtest to read input events from mouse and keyboard

on running it , i see this on terminal

```
Event: time 1425319271.595631, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 105
Event: time 1425319271.595631, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 30
```

"`Event: time 1425319271.595631`"

Does anyone know how to decode this timestamp, i spent couple of minutes on it but could'nt come up with a valid explanation.

Comment: The part before the decimal dot is probably the number of seconds since Jan 01, 1970, the decimals are fractions of a second. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2993/330217

Answer (score 0):

Try the following GNU awk solution:

```
awk -F [" ",] '{ print strftime("%c",$3) }' <<< "Event: time 1425319271.595631, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 105"
```

Set the field delimiter to space or comma and then use awk's strftime function to print the 3rd field in locale format.